# ¿En qué escenario debo usar cada contenedor STL?

Tags: c++, contenedores

Basado en la [pregunta homónima en SO[image]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container).

---

He estado leyendo sobre los contenedores de la STL ([librería de plantillas de C++](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)) y entiendo que cada uno de ellos tienen sus características específicas (que estoy cerca de memorizar)... pero lo que aún no comprendo es en que contextos es mejor usar cada uno de ellos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El siguiente diagrama (basado en [esta respuesta[image]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671607/499359)) está actualizado hasta el estándar C++11 y muestra las decisiones que se deben tomar para escoger entre uno u otro contenedor (haz click en el diagrama para agrandar la imagen).

---

[image]

---