# Asociación varios a varios en POO

Tags: c++, poo

Buenas a todos,

he estado estudiando la asociación uno a uno, que lo entiendo bien, pero cuando he estado viendo la asociación varios a varios, y ahí me pierdo un poco, sobretodo con el contenedor set.
Os voy a poner el fichero de cabecera de una asociación de varios a varios.

> Una persona imparte varias asignaturas.
>
> Una asignatura es impartida por varias personas.

**Clase persona:**

```
#ifndef persona_h_
#define persona_h_

#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Asignatura;  //Declaración adelantada

class Persona
{
public:
  Persona(string nom, string direc);
  void mostrar() const;
  void imparte(Asignatura& asignatura);
  void mostrarAsignaturas() const;
private:
  string nombre;
  string direccion;
  typedef set<Asignatura*> Asignaturas;
  Asignaturas asignaturas;
};

#endif
```

**Clase Asignatura:**

```
#ifndef asignatura_h_
#define asignatura_h_

#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Persona;  //Declaración adelantada

class Asignatura
{
public:
  Asignatura(string nom, string areaa);
  void mostrar() const;
  void impartida(Persona& persona);
  void mostrarPersonas() const;
private:
  string nombre;
  string area;
  typedef set<Persona*> Personas;
  Personas personas;
};

#endif
```

Bien, hasta aquí, entiendo que los que se hace es como una especie de conjunto de punteros desde una persona a varias asignaturas (varias asignaturas serán un conjunto de punteros y cada puntero apunta a cada asignatura que imparte), al contrario que una asignatura es impartida por varias personas.

Lo que no entiendo bien es qué hace las líneas:

```
typedef set<Persona*> Personas;
Personas personas;

typedef set<Asignatura*> Asignaturas;
Asignaturas asignaturas;
```

¿Alguien me podría explicar eso con más detalle o al menos si voy en el camino correcto de cómo se hacer relaciones varios a varios?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Las líneas que no entiendes son alias de tipos, estás diciendo que `set<Persona*>` y `Personas` son lo mismo (puedes escribir uno u otro). Igual sucede con el alias de `set<Asignatura*>` y `Asignaturas`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración @Paula_plus_plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set` no es más que un contenedor de los que están disponibles en la STL (la librería estándar de plantillas de C++).

Este contenedor tiene dos características básicas (tiene más, pero por resumir):

- No admite duplicados
- Los elementos se encuentran **siempre** ordenados

Para este caso entiendo que lo que le interesa al que ha escrito ese código es sobretodo la primera propiedad. Ya que, presumiblemente, le evita hacer determinadas comprobaciones. En el siguiente ejemplo se pueden comprobar estas dos características en funcionamiento. Por si a alguien le da pereza probar el código, el resultado es `123`.

```
std::set<int> numeros;
numeros.insert(2);
numeros.insert(1);
numeros.insert(3);
numeros.insert(1);

for( int numero : numeros )
  std::cout << numero;
```

Por otro lado, `typedef` se usa para definir un alias. En C++ moderno esta palabra puede ser reemplazada por `using`, que es más potente (sobretodo con plantillas) y con resultados más legibles:

```
// Lineas equivalentes en C++11
typedef set<Asignatura*> Asignaturas;
using Asignaturas = set<Asignatura*>;
```

Los alias se usan para no repetir declaraciones largas y repetitivas. Al definir un alias no estás creando un nuevo tipo:

```
using MiEntero = int;
int entero = 5;
MiEntero entero2 = entero; // ok, entero y entero2 son ambos de tipo int
```

Pues bien, para una relación muchos a muchos necesitas, necesariamente, una relación doble, es decir, los elementos del grupo A necesitan enlazar con varios elementos del grupo B y los elementos del grupo B necesitan enlazar con varios elementos del grupo A. Una forma rápida de crear estas relaciones es mediante sendos contenedores en los elementos de cada grupo... tal y como está planteado en este código. El problema que plantea esta solución es que requiere tener todas las listas perfectamente sincronizadas. Es decir, si un alumno se apunta a una asignatura habrá que actualizar la lista de asignaturas del alumno y la lista de alumnos en la asignatura correspondiente... si este proceso falla (y hay que tener en cuenta también que un alumno podría darse de baja), el resultado puede ser bastante decepcionante.

Para este caso concreto también se podría crear esta relación muchos a muchos añadiendo un contenedor en un único grupo... por ejemplo en `Asignaturas`. Para saber las asignaturas en las que está matriculado un alumno habrá que recorrer la lista de asignaturas y preguntar a cada una si el alumno está en su lista:

```
class Persona
{
public:
  // ...
private:
  // typedef set<Asignatura*> Asignaturas;
  // Asignaturas asignaturas;
};

class Asignatura
{
public:
  Asignatura(string nom, string areaa);
  void mostrar() const;
  void impartida(Persona& persona);
  void mostrarPersonas() const;

  bool alumnoMatriculado(Persona const& alumno) const // <<--- NUEVA!!!
  {
    return personas.count(&alumno) != 0;
  }     
private:
  string nombre;
  string area;
  typedef set<Persona*> Personas;
  Personas personas;
};

std::vector<Asignaturas*> listaAsignaturas;
// Se rellena la lista de asignaturas
// ....

// Función que muestra las asignaturas a las que esta
// matriculado un alumno dado
void AsignaturaMatriculadas(Persona const& alumno)
{
  for( Asignatura* asignatura : listaAsignaturas )
  {
    if( asignatura->alumnoMatriculado(alumno) )
      std::cout << asignatura->mostrar() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Pero esta no es una solución que se pueda generalizar... la mejor solución dependerá de los requisitos concretos de cada desarrollo

Comment: Sublime @eferion ! Y si no te importa, ¿qué orden se iría guardando en esas listas? Por ejemplo, en esa lista de Personas o asignaturas, si creo una relación eferion imparte matemáticas y matemáticas es impartida por eferion. Ahí la lista quedaría que Persona el primero sería en la lista eferion y en Asignaturas la primera sería matemáticas, si vuelvo a crear otra relación ProgrammerJr.imparte(lengua). Persona sería 1.Eferion 2.ProgrammerJr y Asignaturas tendría 1.Matemáticas 2. Lengua. ¿Así se irían almacenando en el contenedor set? Gracias por tu brillante explicación.

Comment: Eso depende... el orden por defecto depende del operador `<`, pero el `set` se puede programar para que utilice otro mecanismo de ordenación... o también se puede puentear el citado operador con una sobrecarga...

Comment: De acuerdo, la sobrecarga de operadores aún la tengo pendiente, pero me voy aclarando, nuevamente, muchas gracias @eferion

Comment: @ProgrammerJr como son punteros lo normal es que el orden dependa de la posición de memoria a la que apunta cada puntero... luego el orden puede variar entre ejecuciones

Comment: Más datos sobre los contenedores [STL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL): [¿En qué escenario debo usar cada contenedor STL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54180/en-qu%C3%A9-escenario-debo-usar-cada-contenedor-stl)