# Error al compilar "request for member ‘size’ in ‘*(int*)(& Dia)"

Tags: c++, array, enum

he implementado un código para un enum que contiene los días de la semana, el problema que me sale es con la función `size()`, no entiendo mucho el error, he probado a utilizar un puntero a `end()`, pero no me sale nada. Aquí está el código que he hecho:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    enum Semana{
        Lunes=1, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado, Domingo, DIAS_SEMANA=7};

    int Dia[DIAS_SEMANA];



    for(int i=0; i<(Dia.size()); i++){//La linea del error
        cout<<Dia[i]<<endl;

    }
}
```

El mensaje de error al compilar:

```
 error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘*(int*)(& Dia)’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo que tienes en mente a la hora de realizar este código?
 - ¿Pretendes mostrar los días de la semana como si fuera texto? `Lunes, martes, miércoles, jueves...`
 - ¿O, por el contrario, pretendes mostrar el número asociado a cada día de la semana? `(1, 2, 3, 4...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int Dia[DIAS_SEMANA];
```

Aquí estás declarando un array de tamaño fijo. Si bien `Dia` se gestiona como si fuese un puntero, es decir, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int* ptr = Dia;
```

Los arrays de tamaño fijo tienen ciertas particularidades respecto a los punteros de toda la vida:

- Se almacenan en la pila del programa
- Su tamaño no puede cambiar en tiempo de ejecución
- Su memoria no se puede liberar con `delete` o `free`

Por otro lado, como bien te comenta [@SJuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204370/463), los punteros en C++ **no tienen métodos**... sucede que en C++ los arrays de tamaño fijo, **tampoco** tienen.

Pues bien, aunque no se le pueda preguntar su tamaño directamente, este dato no es imprescindible, ya que tu sabes que el rango de valores va de 0 a `DIAS_SEMANA`, luego el bucle podría quedar así:

```
for(int i=0; i<DIAS_SEMANA; i++)
```

Ahora bien, ya que usas un enumerado para los días de la semana no queda demasiado limpio que le asignes un valor al último elemento de forma manual (que además es el valor que usas de *tope*. Lo normal es dejar el enumerado sin valores:

```
enum Semana{Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado, Domingo, DIAS_SEMANA};
```

O, si queremos generalizarlo todavía más:

```
enum Semana{Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado, Domingo, INICIO = Lunes, DIAS_SEMANA};
```

¿Por qué?

Pues básicamente porque si no las iteraciones quedan un poco raras. Cualquier programador de C++ verá más natural tener un bucle tal que:

```
for( Semana i = INICIO; i < DIAS_SEMANA; i++ )
  Dia[i] = /* ... */;
```

que la alternativa que plantea tu código:

```
for( Semana i = Lunes; i <= DIAS_SEMANA; i++ )
  Dia[i-1] = /* ... */;
  //  ^ OJO que en tu codigo tienes que Lunes=1
```

**Bonus**

Los arrays de tamaño fijo tienen como particularidad adicional que el compilador sabe en todo momento cuántos bytes ocupan, lo que te permite calcular su tamaño de forma "*sencilla*":

```
int numElementos = sizeof(Dia)/sizeof(Dia[0]);
```

Aunque, por otro lado, si deseamos que nuestro array de tamaño fijo tenga métodos, lo que podemos hacer es usar `std::array` (C++11 en adelante):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    enum Semana{ Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado, Domingo, DIAS_SEMANA};

    std::array<int,DIAS_SEMANA> Dia;

    // Iteracion por indices
    for(size_t i=0; i<Dia.size(); i++){
        cout<<Dia[i]<<endl;
    }

    // Iteracion por iteradores
    for(std::array<int,DIAS_SEMANA>::iterator it = Dia.begin(); it != Dia.end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }

    // Iteracion por iteradores (C++11)
    for(auto it = Dia.begin(); it != Dia.end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }

    // for basado en rangos
    for(int item : Dia){
        cout<<item<<endl;
    }
}
```

**Bonus 2**

En C, si no ponemos `void` en los parámetros de una función, lo que conseguimos es que esa función acepte un número indeterminado de parámetros... sin embargo en C++ ese `void` viene implícito, por lo que si dejamos la función simplemente como `int main()` conseguiremos el mismo efecto que con `int main(void)` pero con un código más limpio.

Answer (score 4):

En C/C++, un array es simplemente un puntero que tiene asignada la memoria por el compilador. No es un objeto, y por lo tanto no tiene métodos.

Adicionalmente, como es un puntero, no hay forma de saber directamente el tamaño que tiene. Por fortuna, tu lo sabes en el momento de crearlo (es `DIAS_SEMANA`).

En todo caso, y una vez ya resuelta la pregunta, no está claro que intentas hacer, porque no has inicializado el contenido del array así que solo verás números al azar.

Answer (score 3):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés; lo traduciré:

> ```
> error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘*(int*)(& Dia)’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
> ```

> ```
> error: petición del miembro ‘size’ en ‘*(int*)(& Dia)’, que es del tipo no-clase ‘int’
> ```

El error viene a decir que intentaste llamar a una función miembro (también conocida como método) sobre un tipo de datos que es no-clase (que no es una clase); el tipo sobre el que intentaste llamar `size` es `int`.

El lugar de la llamada es tu línea de error:

```
for(int i=0; i<(Dia.size()); i++){//La linea del error
//              ~~~ <--- Dia es no-clase
```

Si quieres disponer de un método `size` en `Dia`, decláralo como una colección de objetos, no como una formación<sup>1</sup>:

Como [`std::vector` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<int> Dia(DIAS_SEMANA);
```

Como [`std::array` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
std::array<int, DIAS_SEMANA> Dia;
```

Como [`std::list` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list):

```
std::list<int> Dia(DIAS_SEMANA);
```

Si quieres saber qué colección se ajusta mejor a tus necesidades, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54180/2742).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array.*

Answer (score 1):

Según veo en tu código, quieres mostrar los días de la semana, pero utilizas un tipo fundamental (un tipo de dato *int*).
En la [`wikipedia`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Tipos_de_datos) puedes encontrar qué significa, a modo resumido:

> Según la máquina y el compilador que se utilice los tipos primitivos pueden ocupar un determinado tamaño en memoria. La siguiente lista ilustra el número de bits que ocupan los distintos tipos primitivos en la arquitectura x86.
>
> Otras arquitecturas pueden requerir distintos tamaños de tipos de datos primitivos. C++ no dice nada acerca de cuál es el número de bits en un byte, ni del tamaño de estos tipos [...]

Pero en C++, estos datos fundamentales o datos primitivos no son clases. Esto quiere decir que no existe esa función que tú llamas `Dia.size()`.

Pero no nos quedemos únicamente con el primer error que te acaba de salir, sigamos.

- No se recomienda el uso de `using namespace std;`
- Los enumeradores son un tipo de dato. Es mejor para ti, a la larga, que los dejes fuera de cualquier *scope* (fuera de las llaves). De ese modo, podrás saber desde cualquier función qué es el `enum Semana`
- Intentas sacar por pantalla... ¿el qué? ¿Los días de la semana en formato texto? Porque lo que vas a sacar desde `Dia[i]` van a ser todo ceros. Porque tú has especificado que `Dia` es un entero que únicamente puede albergar números en su interior, y por defecto, C++ los pone a 0 todos ellos. Así que, aunque intentes arreglar el fallo de usar el método `.size()`, no te funcionará lo que quieres hacer, que es sacar por pantalla los días de la semana.

Espero que estas aclaraciones te ayuden a mejorar tu código, y así, solventar tu problema.

Comment: Exponer el origen del problema es importante... tanto como proponer alguna solución. Te falta esa segunda parte para que la respuesta pueda considerarse como tal ya que en la pregunta se solicitan soluciones

Comment: En la pregunta expongo que desconozco si quiere mostrar los números equivalentes a los días de la semana o los días de la semana en formato de texto. Son dos formas que no se parecen en absoluto, y mostrar ambas puede aclarar por un lado, y confundir por otro. Por eso he remarcado como una pregunta el qué es lo que pretende, y así evitar el problema XY: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy.

Comment: Si consideras que la respuesta no es lo suficientemente completa entonces deberías (aun no porque no tienes reputación suficiente) usar los comentarios para que aclaren las dudas pertinentes.

Comment: Si hubiera podido en su momento, lo hubiera hecho. Ahora puedo, y lo haré. Gracias.

Comment: sabía que no podías, por eso lo indiqué expresamente en mi comentario. Enhorabuena por tus primeros 50 puntos. Poco a poco se te irán desbloqueado nuevas opciones