# Mostrar strings con estructuras c++

Tags: c++, string, struct

tengo un problema:
Soy alguien muy novato aun en C++, mi problema viene con el `struct`, cuando quiero agregar un nombre por poner un ejemplo, en teoria se agrega a la estructura, pero al quererlo mostrar no sale nada.
Codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Libros
{
    string nombre;
}libro[100];

int cont=-1;

void Insertar()
{
    cont++;
    cout<<"Nombre: ";
    getline(cin,libro[cont].nombre);
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
}

void MostrarTodo()
{
    cout<<"LIBROS DISPONIBLES: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++)
        cout<<libro[i].nombre;
}
```

Mi sospecha es de que esta parte del codigo es la del problema, pero no se cual sea el problema.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, seguí todo lo que me dijeron y funcionó, trataré de mejorar con sus consejos, gracias

Answer (score 3):

> Mi sospecha es de que esta parte del código es la del problema

Mi sospecha es que no muestras nada porque no recopilas nada. No veo en el código que has compartido la parte en que rellenas la formación<sup>1</sup> de libros.

No se si mi sospecha es cierta (creo que es [Eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/242983/2742) quien está en lo cierto), porque tu código es parcial, pero aún con el código que has mostrado hay mucho espacio para la mejora. Tu código no sigue la estructura de lo que se podría considerar programación contemporánea en C++.

1. No uses formaciones<sup>1</sup> a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario, que en tu caso no lo es. Reservando memoria para 100 libros te arriesgas a quedarte corto de espacio (¿qué pasa si quieres más de 100 libros?) o pasarte de largo (malgastas mucha memoria si sólo vas a guardar unas pocas decenas de libros). En su lugar usa un contenedor de datos, elije [el que más se ajuste a tus necesidades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54180/2742).
2. La estructura `Libros` tiene el nombre en plural pero contiene un sólo elemento, la formación<sup>1</sup> `libro` tiene el nombre en singular pero contiene 100 elementos; eso es tremendamente confuso, cambia tu nomenclatura para que sea más coherente.
3. Intenta favorecer el uso de `'\n'` frente al uso de `std::endl`, suele tener un rendimiento mayor la primera opción (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber más del tema).

Con las sugerencias anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a esto:

```
struct Libro
{
    std::string nombre;
};

using lista_libros = std::list<Libro>;

void Insertar(lista_libros &lista)
{
    Libro nuevo_libro;

    std::cout<<"Nombre: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, nuevo_libro.nombre);
    lista.push_back(nuevo_libro);
}

void Mostrar(lista_libros &lista)
{
    std::cout << "LIBROS DISPONIBLES:\n";

    for (const auto &libro : lista)
        std::cout << libro.nombre << '\n';
}
```

Que puede usarse así:

```
int main()
{
    lista_libros cifi, misterio;
    Insertar(cifi);
    Insertar(cifi);
    Insertar(misterio);
    Insertar(misterio);

    Mostrar(cifi);
    Mostrar(misterio);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vQejXxyL5jgtlWzA).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que estás usando `cont` de forma incorrecta.

Se supone que `cont` debe indicar cuántos elementos hay en la lista, mientras que tu lo usas para indicar el índice del último elemento.

Un par de cambios y el código fucionará como esperas.

Lo primero es que `cont` debe empezar en 0 y la razón es que inicialmente **hay 0 elementos** en tu lista:

```
int cont=-0;
```

Lo siguiente a tocar es el método `Insertar`. Ahora `cont` no debe incrementarse hasta que no hayamos añadido un elemento a la lista, es decir, después de haberlo añadido:

```
void Insertar()
{
    cout<<"Nombre: ";
    getline(cin,libro[cont].nombre);
    cont++;
}
```

Nota también que he eliminado la llamada a `ignore`. Si solo usas `getline`, el método `ignore` no es demasiado util (ya has leido toda la línea con `getline`). En cambio si mezclas `cin` y `getline` entonces la llamada a `ignore` debería estar **antes** de llamar a `getline` y esto es así porque `cin` **no elimina** el salto de línea previo.

Finalmente, falta actualizar `MostrarTodo`. No añades ningún separador entre los diferentes nombres. Yo he elegido un salto de línea:

```
void MostrarTodo()
{
    cout<<"LIBROS DISPONIBLES: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++)
        cout<<libro[i].nombre << '\n';
}
```