# ¿Qué significa vector<string>?

Tags: c++, hash

No se que quiere decir esta parte de codigo cuando pone `vector<string>`, ¿A qué se refiere eso?

Es para la implementacion de una tabla hash.

```
vector<string> dividir(string dato){
    vector<string> temp(4);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < dato.size(); i++){
        if(dato[i]==','){
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        temp[j]+=dato[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En C++ existen lo que se conocen como plantillas, que básicamente son moldes para futuras clases y objetos.

En este caso el código está haciendo uso de una plantilla de la librería estándar llamada `std::vector`. Esta plantilla reproduce el comportamiento de una lista de valores. Es básicamente un contenedor que te permite almacenar objetos. ¿Qué tipo de objetos? pues el que esté indicado en la especialización de la plantilla:

```
vector<string>
       ~~~~~~ Especialización
```

Es decir, `vector<string>` es un contenedor para objetos de tipo `string`.

Referencias:

- [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)
- [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
- [plantillas](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=040)

Answer (score 1):

`vector` es una colección o contenedor de objetos, los contenedores de objetos de C++ son homogéneas, es decir: tods los objetos guardados son del mismo tipo. C++ tiene varios tipos de contenedores de objetos con diferentes características y objetivos, echa un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54180/2742) para conocer esas características.

En el caso de `vector`, su característica principal es que todos los elementos que guarda están colocados anexos en memoria, es muy rápido recorrer sus elementos y es potencialmente lento añadir elementos nuevos.

Puedes tener `vector` de diferentes datos, para decidir qué tipo de datos quieres que guarde tu `vector` debes indicarlo entre paréntesis angulares (`<` y `>`), se usa esta notación porque `vector` es una plantilla (tal y como ha explicado [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/266442/2742)).

---

Veamos los usos que le estás dando a `vector<string>` en tu código:

```
vector<string> dividir(string dato){
```

Defines una función llamada `dividir` que recibe un `string` y devuelve un `vector<string>`.

```
vector<string> temp(4);
```

Creas una instancia de `vector<string>` llamada `temp` que nacerá con cuatro elementos.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < dato.size(); i++){
    if(dato[i]==','){
        j++;
        continue;
    }
    temp[j]+=dato[i];
}
```

Recorres los caracteres de `dato` y cada vez que encuentras una coma (`,`) aumentas `j`. Si el caracter encontrado no es una coma, lo concatenas en el `j`-ésimo elemento de `temp`.

A juzgar por el código, esperas que `dato` sea una cadena de caracteres con cuatro palabras separadas por tres comas (por ejemplo: `"uno, dos, tres, cuatro"`) al pasarlo a `dividir` te devolverá un `vector<string>` con cuatro elementos (`"uno"`, `" dos"`, `" tres"`, `" cuatro"`).

Ve con cuidado porque si pasas a `dividir` una cadena con más de tres comas, tu programa fallará en tiempo de ejecución y si pasas menos de tres comas recibirás un `vector<string>` con elementos válidos pero vacíos.