# ¿Cómo borrar el contenido de punteros alojados en una clase?

Tags: c++, punteros

```
class vertice{
public:
    int id;
    int juntadoCon = -1;
    ~vertice() {}
};

class grafoKarger{
private:
    int nv;
    vertice **vertices;
public:
grafoKarger(int v, int a, int m){
        nV = v; nA = a; max = m;
        aristas = new arista[a];
        vertices = new vertice*[v];
        for(int i = 0; i < v; ++i){vertices[i] = nullptr;}
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(clock()));
    }
   ~grafoKarger(){
        for(int i = 0; i < nV; ++i){
            if(vertices[i] != nullptr){
                delete vertices[i];
            }
        }
        delete []vertices;
    }
};
```

El destructor no está funcionando con `**vertices` (vector de punteros, no matriz)
Para eliminar por ejemplo `*clase`, un simple `delete []puntero` me vale, pero aquí he probado tanto en el bucle `delete vertices[i]` como `delete []vertices[i]` y nada
Actualizado con el contructor
Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Al menos, dos cosas.

---

El operador `delete[]` se debe usar en conjunción con el operador `new[]`. Da igual el tipo de puntero en que guardes la memoria, si no la pediste con `new[]` no la deberás borrar con `delete[]`; así que la primera cosa que has hecho mal es no mostrar el código en que pides memoria… si no sabemos cómo la pides no sabremos cómo deberás borrarla.

La segunda cosa que has hecho mal es publicar un código que no compila. En el bucle de `grafoKarger::~grafoKarger` estás usando la variable `nV` como indizadora pero dicha variable no existe, posiblemente pretendías usar la varible `int grafoKarger::nv`.

Mi consejo es que te olvides de punteros, `new` y `delete`, en C++ moderno son (en la mayoría de casos) innecesarios. Si quieres una formación de objetos `vertice`, usa un `std::vector`:

```
class grafoKarger{
private:
    int nv;
    std::vector<vertice> vertices;
};
```

El propio objeto `std::vector` se ocupará de la gestión de memoria, no necesitarás gestionarla a mano. Además si `vertice` no gestiona recursos, no necesitará destructor, y si todos los miembros son públicos, puede ser una `struct`:

```
struct vertice{
    int id;
    int juntadoCon = -1;
};
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, y perdona que no realizase bien la consulta, es la primera que he hecho
Tendré en cuenta lo que me has dicho para la próxima
Finalmente lo he conseguido solucionar
Sobre lo de usar vector, es que es necesitaba los accesos constantes de un tipo de dato estático, y sino me equivoco, vector es una estructura dinámica que tiene coste de acceso lineal.

Comment: `std::vector` no es una estructura dinámica, es un contenedor de datos. La particularidad de `std::vector` es que la inserción de datos es lenta y el acceso a datos es rápido. Echa un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54181/2742) para tener una guía sobre qué contenedor de datos escoger según tus necesidades.