# Crear valor de un arreglo no definido en C++

Tags: c++

¿Cómo le doy un valor a un arreglo no definido? O sea, yo acostumbro hacer esto, pero se que está mal, al menos hasta donde he leído, alguien me puede decir, como definir el valor de un arreglo bien, o como meterle exactamente los valores que quiero, digo se que si lo declaro por ejemplo `#define arreglo[100]` y solo guardo los primeros 5 valores y luego muestro 5, quedan sobrando 95 espacios, eso esta bien o que sería mejor?. Estoy aprendiendo espero su grata respuesta

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main() {

    int valor;
    int valores;

    cout<<"Digite el valor del arreglo"<<endl;
    cin>>valor;
    int arreglo[valor];

    cout<<"Indique los valores a guardar"<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<valor; i++){
        cin>>valores;
        arreglo[i]=valores;

    }
    for(int i=0; i<valor; i++){

        cout<<arreglo[i];

    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Si ves complicada esa documentacion, tambien tienes [este video de The Cherno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PocJ5jXv8No).

Comment: Tambien puedes usar memoria dinamica:realloc(); Pero recuerda liberarla despues: free(arreglo);:

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es usar punteros, crear una variable de tipo puntero entero y definir su espacio después de pedir el tamaño. La unica línea que tendrías que cambiar es la definición de tu arreglo.

```
int *arreglo = new int[valor];
```

Y como buena practica liberar el espacio si es requerido con:

```
delete [] arreglo;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo le doy un valor a un arreglo no definido?

No lo haces, si no lo defines no puedes usarlo.

---

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), los arreglos en memoria automática necesitan que su tamaño sea una constante, no una variable. Por lo tanto este código está mal:

```
cin>>valor;
int arreglo[valor];
```

Si quieres una colección de datos cuyo tamaño se ajuste automáticamente, deberás usar la librería de contenedores, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54181/2742) para decidir qué contenedor te conviene en cada caso.

Te pongo un ejemplo con `std::vector`:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

    using namespace std;

    cout << "Digite el tamaño del arreglo\n";
    int tamanyo;
    cin >> tamanyo

    vector<int> arreglo(tamanyo, 0); // Un vector de 'tamanyo' elementos inicializados a '0'

    cout << "Indique los valores a guardar\n";
    for (auto &valor : arreglo)
        cin >> valor;

    for (const auto &valor : arreglo)
        cout << valor;

    return 0;
}
```